# Linux Mint autoupdates

Tags: linux-mint, auto-updates

Under mac and Windows, the updates can be done automatically. For certain people, this is great. In Linux Mint 17, I can't find an option to enable the updates automatically.

I know there is a trick, based on Ubuntu, with command line to enable the autoupdates, but the security levels of Mint in updates manager are not respected (i.e.: unattended-upgrades).

Please, could you tell us how to, or which way can, enable the updates automatically with respect of the security levels of the updates manager (levels 1,2,3,4,5)?